# In SGU: Blockade (2.19) where is the actual location that was used for the city?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe, real-location

I'm talking about the "crap, we dialed Pittsburgh" city.  Was that a set or an actual city/town? And if it was a city/town, does anyone know where that is?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like the location is Terminal City Ironworks in East Vancouver.

http://vancouverisawesome.com/2011/05/12/yvrshoots-stargate-universe-sgu-meets-its-destiny/

> Four months later, I found Stargate
>   Universe filming a planetary visit at
>   the old Terminal City Ironworks site
>   (often used by film & TV productions)
>   in East Vancouver. SGU filmed there
>   for several days with a CGIed Stargate
>   inside one of the buildings and
>   virtually the entire cast there, with
>   the exception of Robert Carlyle (Rush)
>   and David Blue (Eli) left aboard the
>   Destiny in studio. I photographed a
>   green-screen on the roof to CGI a
>   scene of Louis Ferreira (Col. Young)
>   looking down on a deserted city: “It
>   wasn’t abandoned. These people were
>   wiped out.” I didn’t stick around once
>   they finished the roof scene and moved
>   inside, so I didn't get to witness any
>   of the cast`s crazy antics or
>   shenanigans often involving cutup
>   Ferreira, but I did see a happy and
>   relaxed Jamil Walker Smith (Master
>   Sgt. Greer) and Alaina Huffman (TJ),
>   with her two young children, chatting
>   outside their trailers with crew and
>   fans while Ming-Na (Camille Wray)
>   strolled around the block in the sun.
>   SGU filmed other key scenes of this
>   deserted city at the old Watchmen set
>   in Burnaby. And the scenes ended up in
>   the penultimate episode of the SGU
>   series, in fact of the entire Stargate
>   TV franchise.

Also a link to an interesting thread here:
http://forum.gateworld.net/threads/80075-Blockade-(219)-General-Discussion/page8
where there is some arguing as to whether it is the same location as Sateda:
[image]

Comment: You can re-assign this as the correct answer.  Especially since it totally answers the question.  Even if it's your own question, this is totally fine, per the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen nothing stating for certain, but as SGU is filmed in Vancouver, I would guess that it's either a street in Vancouver or the studio back lot there.